# Wcf remote procedure calls

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have created a custom release/deployment log application for a large organization. Front end has been implemented in Adobe AIR backed up by PHP using amfphp for communication. Performance has been excellent. Currently, I have been asked to integrate some windows features (i.e outlook calendar, sharepoint). I thought it would be easier going with a native client and I tried creating a mockup in wpf(managed, but still native) and it looks really  good. My problem though is on the server side. I had in mind wcf, but to my surprise it is a soap framework(xml) and does not support object exchange between the client and the server. So my problem is how to sent to the client a "user" object as I already do with amphph?

Comment: Yes, WCF is a **message-based** (serialized XML) system - it's **not** an RPC system. So what is your question then?? And BTW: WCF supports both SOAP **and REST** - just to be clear...

Comment: To verify it. Actually It is advertised as an XML-RPC technology and it is confusing. Ok my question is what options do I have for "genuine" RPC with wpf?

Comment: I think I have my answer. I have heard about Remoting in .net, but I thought it was something obsolete and that it would be replaced by wcf. After some searching, I have concluded that wcf is something equivalent to OSB or a BPEL implementation, which is something great for enterprises with heterogenous systems, that need integration, but that is not the case for me. System.Runtime.Remoting, a console application with an IIS server will do.

Comment: @user: you need to do more reading. You're very wrong. Remoting has been replaced by WCF. WCF does SOAP, REST, as well as allowing custom communications stacks. It does not support XML-RPC out of the box, but I believe there's a way to get that. BTW, XML-RPC is not "RPC". RPC is a concept that's been around much longer than XML-RPC. XML-RPC, BTW is what SOAP is based on. It has largely been superseded by SOAP.

Answer (score 0):

amfphp does binary serialization of ActionScript objects.  You should be able to pass objects back and forth using serialized XML using a .NET class that represents your data, unless you're doing something fairly complex. The service references automatically expose the types used in WCF method parameters and return types to the client.

The difficultly with passing objects back and forth with WCF usually lies within the change tracking and concurrency.  If you add some audit fields (i.e. timestamp) to the class you use for passing back and forth, that should handle concurrency.  As for what type of concurrency handling you use to apply changes, that is up to your business rules.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The idea is to migrate the whole application with a native windows application, which will make future improvements far more feasible and use a microsoft server technology for better integration. But wcf seems out of the question. I have searched the last few days and found out that wcf handles concurrency only through IIS or through WAS available for Vista and higher( which is out of the question as the server will run on 2003). There technologies that you access objects on the server as if they were locally, but with .net you have to (de)serialize. It's crazy.

Comment: @user: you really need to stop researching and instead ask some questions. Your answers are all wrong. IIS is available on Windows Server 2000 and up.

Comment: I have to agree with John, @user you need to start at the beginning with a good book on WCF, you're getting yourself in a bit of a knot.

Comment: Did I say that IIS is not for Server 2003? You should read more carefully. I said that WAS is not. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using a proprietary technology on your server side - amfphp, it's a flash specific thing, you need to implement something standard that your client can consume, and there are a lot of options.

1. SOAP services from PHP ( https://www.php.net/soap )
2. JSON ( http://pear.php.net/package/Services_JSON ) consume it in .NET with JSON.NET ( http://json.codeplex.com/ )
3. Simple REST (Define your own text based data structures)

I think SOAP is a bit verbose, and rolling your own is tedious. Coming from a web/PHP background I imagine JSON will be a comfortable fit.

(You may need to use the .NET WebClient class as well)